# How to prevent infinite loop with Google visualization setSelection()?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm running into a situation using the Google visualization API for charts. When the user clicks on a chart item, it calls an event handler that opens a popup (but in the example below, just does an alert). it works, but only once; after you click on the item, it remains selected and so does not fire the event handler again (which is listening for a 'select' event).

The documentation says to call the setSelection() method and pass in nothing, null, or an empty array as the argument, and that will deselect everything. But when I add that at the end of the event handler, it actually reselects the selected item and gets caught in an infinite loop. A simplified, working version of my code is below:

```
    <!---Google Charts--->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
            google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var container = document.getElementById('timelineholder');
                var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
                var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                var options = {tooltip: {isHtml: true}};

                //Add columns
                dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Employer'});
                dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Job ID'});
                dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
                dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start Date'});
                dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End Date'});

                //Add Rows
                dataTable.addRows([
                                    ['Some Company',
                                    '123456',
                                    'Some Tooltip Text',
                                    new Date(2016,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                                    new Date(2016,8,1,0,0,0,0)],
                    ]);

                chart.draw(dataTable, options);

                //make rows clickable
                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(){
                    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
                    var placementId = dataTable.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);

                    alert(placementId);
                    chart.setSelection();//this should effectively deselect the row so it can be clicked on again and fire off the handler again. Instead, it's re-selecting the selected row and causing an infinite loop
                });
            }
    </script>

<div id="timelineholder" class="timelineholder"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timeline` charts are the only i've run across without a `setSelection` [method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#methods)

so it's causing an error

also once something is selected, it cannot be unselected (on `Timeline` charts)
without re-drawing the chart

try...
`chart.draw(dataTable, options);`

instead of...
`chart.setSelection();`

Comment: One follow-up -- using chart.draw(dataTable, options); works, but the tooltip doesn't disappear after you click on the timeline item. So instead of that I just call "drawChart();", and the tooltip disappears as it should.

Comment: Two follow-up -- to get the draw function to work as expected, call the clearChart() function first

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: I was struggling with an infinite loop using the google chart's timeline and i found out that I filled the second column (label) with a 'number' instead of a 'string'. I just called .toString and the problem vanished...

I could not reproduce it in fiddle though.

I was also using ng2-google-charts.

Maybe it may help someone else.